# Combine three tables into one when viewing

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables as seen in this image and I want to present it as seen in the last table. I can't figure out how to solve it - right now I'm using three nestled calls to display it.

First I loop through `Customer` to display all of them. Inside this loop I have a loop that goes through `OrderCustom` and inside that I check if there is a `CustomerOrderCustom` with the right `Customer_id` and `OrderCustom_id`.

Not only am I using a lot of queries but the view shows `OrderCustom` items that now `Customer` are using, in this case Zip Code. I'm using MySQL 5.

[image: schema]

Comment: What database are you using, and what version?

Comment: This problem is caused by the poor database design.  If you are an administrator of this database you should normalize it.  Queries like this would be trivial...

Comment: Mark: MySQL 5 user589983: How should I design it then? New values to OrderCustom are added along the way.

Comment: @user589983 `poor database design`?!? His design looks perfect to me - even normalized, unlike most. What would you change?

Comment: @ANeves I agree that this is poor database design.  It's not a great way of normalization.  Just try writing a query to solve his problem, and you'll see how not fun it is.

Comment: @ANeves One of the many problems with this design is that it does not allow for meaningful constraints on the Custom_value field.  It would make more sense to me if the db had unique fields for these values (State, Country, Zip, etc) on the Customer table or maybe an Address table related to the Customer table.

Comment: The problem with that is that new values will be added to ordercustom in the future.

Comment: If you sacrifice your design simply to save the time of adding new columns you will always struggle with simple operations like this. I would take the time now to plan out as much of the details as possible and go with a more disciplined design.  Notice that you have not received any answers after 30 views...

Comment: I understand, but it's not me but the user that's going to add the new fields. I can't go and add new fields all the time. I would gladly change the design but I can't forsee all the fields that the user could want.

Comment: This database is not even in 1NF since it's impossible to state what the domain for Custom_value is.

Comment: @HapiDjus - The other problem you have here is the "Inner Platform effect." In essence you are creating a database system inside a database system. You can make it work, but it will be painful every time you have to do even the simplest of queries against it. Also, you get the anti-bonus that you negate a lot of the optimizations the DB engine would normally give you. So for all the extra work you will have to do you are rewarded with a worse performing system. The flexibility is not worth the cost. Just add the columns you need now and add more if you need them later.

Comment: FYI: SharePoint does something similar to this, and it is a key reason I hate that product, and also the reason it is REALLY bad at handling large datasets.

Answer (score 2):

This is an entity-attribute-value database design.  It is not relational in design and you will not be able to manipulate it with relational operations (such as JOINs) except for the most trivial examples.

If you are determined to store this non-relational data in a relational database you'll be dependent on either your own code or some EAV-based object serialization and deserialization library for whatever programming language you're using.  SQL will be of little use to you.

If you are really required to use a model like this for this project (that is, you cannot adopt a relational model) then, if it is not too late in the development process, I would suggest abandoning SQL and reading up on XML, XPath, and XSLT which are probably a better fit for storing and recovering data in which each entry can have a different structure.

**Bonus Article:** ["Why Entity-Attribute-Value is bad"](http://www.lunaticprogrammer.com/2008/08/why-entity-attribute-value-is-bad.html)